# How to add dynamically an extern javascript button ansyer inside a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to add a button close to inputfield via an injections script.
This button is in relation with ajax php and must fill an inputfield

If I include my javascript inside my file, I have no problem. But how to do that with an external javascript:
Note : inputfield is inside a loop in relation with the language (en, fr ...)

my php file :

```
<?php
for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
?>
                    <div class="row" id="productsSeoTitle<?php echo $i ?>">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="<?php echo $Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?>"
                         class="col-1 col-form-label"><?php echo $Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4 input-group" id="products_head_title_tag<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <?php echo '&nbsp;' . HTML::inputField('products_head_title_tag[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', SeoAdmin::getProductsSeoTitle($pInfo->products_id, $languages[$i]['id']), 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="products_head_title_tag_' . $i . '"', false); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

?>
```

My external php/js file (injection in file above)

```
     for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
        $this->app->loadDefinitions('Module/Hooks/seo_title');
        $question = $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', $languages[$i]['id']);
        $seo_page_title[$i] = $question .  $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, $languages[$i]['id']);
        // Output the value of $seo_page_title as a JavaScript variable
        echo "var seo_page_title_$i = '".addslashes($seo_page_title[$i])."';\n";
      }

Button inclusion
      $content .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit-button-' . $i . '">';
      $content .= '<i class="bi-chat-square-dots" title="' . $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title') . '"></i>';
      $content .= '</button>';

$output = <<<EOD
<script defer>
$('[id^="products_head_title_tag"]').append(
  '{$content}'
);
</script>

<script defer>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Loop through all the submit buttons
  $('[id^="submit-button-"]').click(function() {
    // Get the index of the button
    let index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];

    let message = "{$seo_page_title[0]}"; 
    let ajax = $("#ajax").val();

    $.post("{$url}", {message: message, ajax: ajax}, function(data) {
      $("#output-input").val(data);
      $("#products_head_title_tag_" + index).val(data); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
EOD;
        return $output;
```

Across this code, I have my ajax response but the input is not filled.

Thank you.

```
<div class="col-md-4 input-group" id="products_head_title_tag<?php echo $i; ?>">
   <?php echo '&nbsp;' . HTML::inputField('products_head_title_tag[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', SeoAdmin::getProductsSeoTitle($pInfo->products_id, $languages[$i]['id']), 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="products_head_title_tag_' . $i . '"', false); ?>
              </div>
```

Progress,
I idinfied my problem about the completion, come from this line I remove the loop, The problem come $i

```
//      for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
        $this->app->loadDefinitions('Module/Hooks/ClicShoppingAdmin/seo_title');
        $question = $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', $languages[0]['id']);
        $seo_page_title[0] = $question .  $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, $languages[0]['id']);
        // Output the value of $seo_page_title as a JavaScript variable
        echo "var seo_page_title_0 = '".addslashes($seo_page_title[0])."';\n";
  //    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind the event handler to all elements of a class, like `$(".submit-button").click(...)`?

Comment: And then use navigation methods to access related elements.

Comment: Could you explain me more ?

Comment: yes, I try to do that

Comment: I started writing an answer that gets rid of using `$i` in the injections script, but I couldn't figure out how to handle `$seo_page_title[$i]`. Is the injection script included during the `for` loop?

Comment: Just above $content I have that, but I am not sur is correct for the js
for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
        $seo_page_title[$i] =  $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question') . ' ' . $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, $languages[$i]['id']);
      }

Comment: I don't understand how all these different parts fit together. If you include the injection file inside the loop, it should be able to use `$i`.

Comment: Hello, Tkj, I added some information as I can to help you to understand the context and my progress. I can click now on the button, answer form ajax, but the input fields is not filled

Comment: "The problem come $i" - what does that mean?

Comment: $i is inside the loop (represent the language), I have a first loop in my main code, and another loop inside the hooks(javascript/injection). I mean, the button is created twice. That's why I have a problem.